# How to convert MongoDB\MapReduceResult to array?

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm using MongoDb [php-library](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library) in my code. I like how it works. Now, I'm able to get MapReduceResult like so:

```
    $map = new MongoDB\BSON\Javascript('function() { 
    emit( { 
      incident: this.guid, 
    },{ 
      data: [this]
    });
}');
$reduce = new MongoDB\BSON\Javascript('function(key, values) {
    var out = [];
    values.forEach(function(d){
        Array.prototype.push.apply(out, d.data);
    });
    return { data: out };
}');
$out = ['inline' => 1];
$res = $collection->mapReduce($map, $reduce, $out);
```

I tried to get an array out of it - `$res->toArray();`, but MapReduceResult does not have such a method. So, how can I convert it to a useful array? I tried it like so:

```
$it = $res->getIterator();
var_dump(iterator_to_array($it, true));
```

But I get an array of `BSONDocument`s, whereas I need a simple PHP array in order to return it to the client in the form of JSON.

Comment: Does anybody use PHP for connecting to MongoDB?

Comment: Try `$res->result->getIterator();`  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#output

Comment: @Valijon. $res->result is NULL.

Comment: Try to put out any collection name to ser if mapReduce works as expected...